# Namespace methods inside class

Tags: ruby, class, namespaces

I'm writing a wrapper class to integrate with Clickup's API and I want define my methods to match their rest api structure. So I was thinking it would be cool if I could namespace the methods inside the class, for example:

```
class Clickup
    
    def initialize
        # sets some variables e.g. api token
    end

    module Users

        def get_all
            # make call to get all users
        end

    end

    module Lists

        def get_all
            # make call to get all lists
        end

    end
end
```

Then I can write my code like something like this:

```
clickup = Clickup.new

@users = clickup::users.get_all
@lists = clickup::lists.get_all
```

The problem is I don't know if this is even do-able and how to call the method thats inside the module.

Does anyone know how to do this, or is there a better way to do it?

I ideally only want to instatiate the clickup class once and need variables set in the root of the class to be accessible by the namespaced methods e.g. the api token.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't really doable. Namespacing is only available on the class, not instance level, so `Clickup::Users` would work but `Clickup.new::Users` can't. You could maybe do it with some metaprogramming, but it'd be a bit complicated and make your code more difficult to understand.

Don't make the mistake of thinking a namespace is anything more than that - *namespacing*. Just because A::B has B nested in A, doesn't mean there is *any* relationship between them. They have completely separate state and behavior.

The following is a somewhat similar approach that could work, though it makes you have to rewrite `initialize` a few times. This can be a good thing though. It means that each of the classes works independently and can have only the *required* dependencies passed in.

*note, I took the liberty of changing the 4-space indentation to 2 since this is the norm in Ruby.*

```
class Clickup   
  def initialize(config)
    @config = config
  end

  def users
    Users.new(@config)
  end

  def lists
    Lists.new(@config)
  end

  class Users
    def initialize(config)
      @config = config
    end

    def get_all
      # make call to get all users
    end
  end

  class Lists
    def initialize(config)
      @config = config
    end

    def get_all
      # make call to get all lists
    end
  end
end
```

And usage would be similar to your idea:

```
clickup = Clickup.new(foo: "bar")
clickup.users.get_all # calls Users#get_all
clickup.lists.get_all # calls Lists#get_all
```

Actually, I just remembered something ... `::` actually *is* an alias for `.`. This isn't something normally used, but technically it is possible to use the exact call signature you wanted:

```
clickup = Clickup.new(foo: "bar")
clickup::users.get_all # calls Users#get_all
clickup::lists.get_all # calls Lists#get_all
```

Comment: `Users` and `Lists` should be classes too – you can't instantiate modules. (and they could inherit from a base `Collection` class which implements most methods)

Comment: What @Stefan said. Since `List` and `User` do not define `new` as a method of the module this will result in a `NoMethodError`. Since these are modules and the signature for the methods does not include `self` and the methods are not declared as module functions trying to call the methods directly would also raise a `NoMethodError`